# ACTION_DIAL cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a small problem with my code, I used the Intent class to start the service call, like this:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("tel:067614214367");
        Intent DialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,uri);
        startActivity(DialIntent);
    }
```

the error message appears : ACTION_DIAL cannot be resolved or is not a field

please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set the flag:

```
DialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

So your final method will be like this :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("tel:067614214367");
        Intent DialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,uri);
        DialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(DialIntent);
    }
```

**EDIT :**

Note that `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` brings up the dialer, but doesn't actually make the phone call. You can replace the line shown (`Intent DialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,uri);)`)with this line:

```
dialIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
```

So :

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent();
dialIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:067614214367"));
```

you'll  have to declare the **android.permission.PHONE_CALL** permission in your Android manifest file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have the same error messege with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK cannot be resolved or is not a field),

Comment: have you added the permission in your androidmanifest.xml ? : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: @abdoBim i have edited my answer try it , i wish it works now :)

Comment: yes I added this tag in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: it displays the same error